# Opening and Viewing "Additional Files" in ArcGIS Layer Package

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layer-package

In ArcGIS I've created a layer package with several shapefiles (that include symbology and labels) so I can send it to a coworker. In addition, I've added a spreadsheet document under the "Additional Files" tab (see image below) so my co-worker can cross check it with the attribute table.

My question is, how do my co-worker open or view that spreadsheet from the layer package? When I opened the layer package in ArcMap there is no mentioning of the attachment in any of the menus.

I've researched ESRI's help pages on the subject and none of them specify how to open the additional files, only how to add them.

[image]

Comment: Did you try the [Extract Package tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/extract-package.htm)? "Packages with attachments will have their attached files unpacked to the commondata\userdata\ subfolder in the Output Folder. Typically the files inside a package are supporting files, like a .pdf, .docx or an image. You will need to navigate to the extracted directory in Windows Explorer to open these files."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default location for package install/download is:

"C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages"

If you browse to that directory in your file explorer you should find the attachments inside of the layer package sub-directory.

**Example**: If your layer package name was TestPackage the additional files would be located here: "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages\TestPackage\commondata\userdata\"